# How to avoid vertical glare in astrophotography?

Tags: astrophotography

I recently took a few night shots of the Milky Way, but found that I kept getting this weird vertical glare and I don't know why. The below image shows it exaggerated by lights in the distance as well. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: strange lines]

Update: I finally got to take a look at my lens and here's what I found:

[image: Smudge]

That is probably the culprit.  Bummer I won't get a chance to shoot the Milky Way agin soon.  I'd really like to get that shot.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have a protective filter on the lens?

Comment: No filter, just an EM-5 with a [12mm lens](http://www.getolympus.com/us/en/m-zuiko-12mm-f2-0.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your front lens (or filter) is smudged in that direction , try to clean it dry,..

Comment: It could also be on the back element of the lens...

Comment: Did you try to clean it?

Comment: I did not. I haven't yet had time to take a look, but this seems reasonable.  I was in Mexico and it was humid so I had probably wiped the lens, but not cleaned it thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

I've gotten the same thing after wiping off the front of the lens when not waiting long enough for a cool camera to warm up before removing it from my bag in a warm, humid environment.

[image: example of moisture smeared across lens]

Answer (score 0):

It's definetly something about that we were discussing earlier, but possible on some inner lens element :(, try it with some other lens. ( :( because you can't do anything against that by yourself)